# What is the mathematical meaning behind D[f]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, operators

```
y = a + b x;
```

I can understand this  output of the ordinary differentiation of `y` w.r.t. `x`

```
D[ y, x]
```

> ```
> b
> ```

but I don't understand the mathematical meaning of this output

```
D[y]
```

> ```
> a + b x
> ```

In fact there is no matching usage of `D[f]` (with only single argument) in the *Mathematica* documentation. Usually *Mathematica* will flag up argument count mismatch when running, e.g.

> ```
> "... called with m argument; n arguments are expected"
> ```

Can anyone help me to understand the meaning of `D[f]`?
Is this a bug or undocumented behavior in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a bug if you consider this behavior as a logical continuation of the following permissible syntax:

```
D[a + b x^3, x, x, x]

(* ==> 6 b *)

D[a + b x^3, x, x]

(* ==> 6 b x *)

D[a + b x^3, x]

(* ==> 3 b x^2 *)

D[a + b x^3]

(* ==> a + b x^3 *)
```

The point is that a `Sequence` of variables is allowed following the first argument of `D`. And the empty sequence in the last example is a special case of this.

Comment: That's a very good and compelling reasoning for the output it provides... In my earlier comment, I didn't say undefined syntax, but _invalid_ syntax (I can see how "invalid" is incorrect terminology as well... I should've said "undocumented"). I would consider this to either be a documentation oversight (if this use is intended) or speculative... the definition might as well be `D[f_] := f` as I had said in my comment :)

Comment: @rm-rf You may well be right - but I thought it's OK to postulate "innocent until proven guilty"...

Comment: In other words, `D[f[x]]` is the zeroth derivative, $f^(0)(x)$, the same as `Derivative[0][f][x]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Right. I wonder if there's also a continuation to negative derivatives like in `Derivative[-1]`, which is indeed the integral. Maybe `f[x[D]]`?

Comment: @Jens  I'm not sure about `f[x[D]]`; however, I'd expect `D[f[x], {x,-1}]` would be ok, but it doesn't work.